# Get the name of an image

Tags: images

How do I take the name of an image? For example: I upload images `image_name.jpg`. So the URL is `http://localhost/xxxx/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/image_name.jpg`.

So I just wanted to take the name of the image, not the URL. 
How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have and succeed. 
How to post_mime_type different? 
I have added the post_mime_type in functions.php

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'pixelo_upload_types');
   function pixelo_upload_types($existing_mimes=array()) {
   $existing_mimes['otf'] = 'otf';
   $existing_mimes['ttf'] = 'ttf';
return $existing_mimes; }
```

then I tried here and it did not work.

```
<?php
$args = array(
'numberposts'     => -1,
'orderby'         => 'menu_order',
'order'           => 'ASC',
'post_type'       => 'attachment',
'post_parent'     => $post->ID,
'post_mime_type' => 'ttf'
);

$font = get_posts($args);
if($font) {
    foreach($font as $key => $data) : ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $data->ID; ?>"><?php echo $data->post_title; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach;
} ?>
```

Please help me. Please help me. How can I make it?

Comment: Sorry... 1) Your answer appears to be addressing something different from the question and 2) Your answer asks a question.